# Tesseract OCR: Detect non-white background

Tags: python, ocr, tesseract

I am writing python to detect the digits on non-white background with following code:

```
import pytesseract, re
from PIL import Image

pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Tesseract 
OCR\\tesseract.exe'
text = pytesseract.image_to_string(Image.open("image3.jpg"))
print (text)
```

However, nothing is detected....how to make it work?  Thanks.

[digits on non-white background](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UHzNu.jpg)

Comment: First try to call tesseract directly from command line without Python. If this doesn't work either, it may be a Tesseract-specific problem.

Comment: Try to binarize image before calling tesseract. Even though tesseract uses some binarization techniques inside it, you are still encouraged to do it on your side (see [tesseract FAQ](https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/wiki/ImproveQuality))